# Is int implicitly signed (C++)?

Tags: c++, int, unsigned, signed

In C++, when I say `int i = 0;`

is the int now automatically `signed int i = 0;` or `unsigned int i = 0;`?

I haven't found an answer through Google

Comment: Yes, it is signed. But: if you google [this](https://www.google.hu/search?q=int+signed+or+unsigned+by+default), then the third hit is [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signedness).

Comment: Yes, note that `signed` is generally redundant, except when used with `char`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The C++11 standard ([draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)) §3.9.1.2 has this to say;

> There are ﬁve standard signed integer types : “signed char”, “short int”, **“int”**, “long int”, and “long long int”.

The C11 standard ([draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)) §6.2.5.4 has this to say;

> There are ﬁve standard signed integer types, designated as signed char, short int, **int**, long int, and long long int

It would seem they're both in agreement that **int** is a signed type.

([C89](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#3.1.2.5) §3.1.2.5 also agrees, so it would seem to have been that way as far as I can go back)

Answer (score 0):

Its's signed. You can prove that to yourself by decrementing the integer and seeing that negative values are provided, rather than it wrapping back round to the maximum number for an unsigned integer.

Comment: What's the difference between `-1` and `UINT_MAX` ?

Comment: `UINT_MAX` is the highest possible value for an unsigned integer. `-1` is the integer value directly below zero.

Comment: @Paul R: They are different; -1 is an int, UINT_MAX is an unsigned int. However, (unsigned int)(-1) and UINT_MAX are the same.

Comment: This would only prove that it is signed on your platform. It is no proof that it is implicitly signed everywhere.

Comment: And how would you tell the difference ? If you look at the value in a debugger they are the same. If you `printf("%d", -1);` and `printf("%d, UINT_MAX);` you get the same output. Ditto for `%u`. So how does decrementing an int past 0 tell you whether it's signed or unsigned ?

Comment: @Paul R: Try float a = float(-1); float b = float(UINT_MAX); and inspect a and b in your debugger.

Comment: Anyway, for a given platform, a better test would be `std::numeric_limits<int>::is_signed()`.

Comment: @Paul R: printf("%d, UINT_MAX); is equivalent to printf("%d, int(UINT_MAX));

Comment: To clarify: my point is that the idea of "proving it for yourself" in the answer above is bogus - it tells you nothing about whether int is implicitly signed or unsigned.

Comment: @PaulR, `printf("%d", UINT_MAX);` causes undefined behaviour. However, `printf("%d", -1);` is well-defined , and if the output is "-1" it would tell you that `int` is signed (on that implementation). `%d` is the specifier for `int`.  I guess this is moot though, as if you accept that `%d` is the modifier for `int` because the standard says so, then you should also accept the standard's word that `int` is signed.

Answer (score -2):

it is signed int by default in c++

Comment: This is correct. But you may want to provide some links or a documentation which says that. Otherwise this classifies as a comment only, not an answer.